# Extracting TCP data with Scapy

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, nonetype

I'm currently trying to extract the payload of a TCP packet (which is just a single letter) with Scapy, but it keeps giving me a NoneType exception after going through the first two packets.

```
from scapy.all import *
import base64

capture = rdpcap('Data.pcapng') # pcap file

output = open('output.bin','wb') # save dumped data to output.bin

for packet in capture:
    # if packet is ICMP and type is 8 (echo request)
    if packet[TCP].src == '172.16.139.128': 
        output.write(packet[TCP].payload) # write packet data to output.bin
```

The exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 372, in __getattr__
    fld, v = self.getfield_and_val(attr)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exploit.py", line 10, in <module>
    if packet[TCP].src == '172.16.139.128': 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 374, in __getattr__
    return self.payload.__getattr__(attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 372, in __getattr__
    fld, v = self.getfield_and_val(attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 1600, in getfield_and_val
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: src
```

Does anyone know what's causing this? It should be outputting more.

Comment: It seems that your `TCP` cannot be used as a key. A breakpoint to check its value ?

Comment: I would check `packet[TCP]` value as well and inspect its attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IP source address is in the IP header, not in TCP's.  Hence, the error.  So if you want to check whether the packet comes from `172.16.139.128` and has a TCP payload, the appropriate test would be:

```py
if IP in packet and packet[IP].src == '172.16.139.128' and TCP in packet:
   output.write(packet[TCP].payload)
```